# Setting request body in controller testing with Stripes

Tags: unit-testing, http, mocking, stripes

I'm creating an ActionBean that takes a request that contains an XML message. Is there a way for me to simulate this operation using the mocking framework included in Stripes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized I could probably just mock it from a custom ActionBeanContext method while the actual application context implementation will access the request object directly.

Answer (score 0):

While the Stripes mock framework does a good job, I often find it cleaner to just unit test the action bean as if it were just a POJO. For more complex test I use [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) (or [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/)).

Comment: I do this when I have the chance but there are some scenarios that really ask for the Stripes testing framework.